# Some laptops USB not working on docking station

Tags: usb, bios, laptop

This is an odd one. I have two laptops (on an estate of 250) which won't recognise the USB ports on the docking station.

Have swapped out hardware, and tried the disks in a new chassis and it is down to the disk.

So far so normal - must be an OS issue, right? Well that's where it gets weird.

The USB issue also manifests at BIOS level (i.e. you can't move around in the BIOS with a USB keyboard connected to the docking station) and on an Ubuntu image booted from USB.

Don't think it's necessarily relevant, but they are Lenovo T431s laptops, on a Mini-Series Plus Series 3 (4338) docking station.

Comment: The bios issues indicated that it is not a disk/os level problem. Have you checked the settings (Legacy USB, etc) in the bios?

Comment: Looking at that now. One other thing worth mentioning is that I took an image of this disk, and put it on a "known good" disk, and the issue came with it.

Comment: Booting with Legacy BIOS still has the same issue, as does disabling UEFI support